# i develop startup video while app loading instead of image.and also navigate to next page with push viewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, pushviewcontroller

i develop splash video while app loading instead of image.and also navigate to next page with push viewcontroller in ios.But i dono this was correct code or not.But i use this some issue was happenn in third page but it was not used means my app loading fine.My sample code here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self videopage];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)videopage
{
    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz.opening_ani.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController * videos =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    videos.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    videos.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:videos.view];
    [videos play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(startParsing) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil]; 
  //[self startParsing];
}

-(void)startParsing
{
    ViewController * navigation=[[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigation animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please should with the following code. i think, your notification object is `nil` so didn't working.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startParsing:)
                                             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:videos];

- (void)startParsing:(NSNotification *)noti
{
   ViewController * navigation=[[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigation animated:NO];
}
```